# Expected time for a Markov chain to reach a state

Tags: probability, expected-value, markov-chains, random-walk

Assume we have a bag containing balls. At each time step, a ball is added with probability $p$ or a ball is removed with probability $1-p>p$. If the bag is empty, it remains so with probability $1-p$ or a ball is added with probability $p$.
So that, the sequence of number of balls in the bag at each time $n \in \mathbb{N}$ forms an irreductible (aperiodic) Markov chain:

\begin{align}
& X_{n+1} = X_n + \mathbb{1}_{ \{ W_{n+1}=H \} } - \mathbb{1}_{ \{ W_{n+1}=T \} }, & \text{ if } X_n>0, \\
& X_{n+1} = \mathbb{1}_{ \{ W_{n+1}=H \} }, & \text{ if } X_n=0, \\
& X_0 \in \mathbb{N}
\end{align}

with $(W_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ being a sequence of indedepent random variables such that, for all time step $n$, $\mathbb{P}(W_n=H)=1-\mathbb{P}(W_n=H)=p$.

I am interesting in computing the mean time $T^0$ to empty the bag given the initial number of balls is $1$: $X_0=1$ a.s.; I wrote
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}_1[T^0] = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} n \mathbb{P}_1 (T^0 = n).
\end{equation}
The event ${T^0=n}$, given ${X_0=1}$ corresponds (unless I am mistaken) to the event that the number of balls is increased by 1 $k$ times and decreased (by one) $k+1$ times, for $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $k+k+1=1+2k=n$, but the order matters (we should start with (at least) one increase of $1$ ball).
All the paths going from state $X_0=1$ to $X_n=0$ should thus have same probability $p^k (1-p)^{k+1}$ and
$$
\mathbb{P}_1 (T^0 = n) = \#\{ \text{Number of possible paths from $1$ to $0$ that reach state $0$ exactly at time $n$ } \} \times p^k (1-p)^{k+1}.
$$

I have two questions then:
i) What would be the (cardinal) number of such paths?
ii) Is there a more "direct" way to compute the mean time in question using a general result? For instance, if interested in computed the average mean **return** time to state $0$, the invariant probability measure $\pi$ would be useful as
$$
\mathbb{E}_0[T^0]=1/\pi(0). 
$$

Thank you!

Comment: This Markov chain has surely been analyzed many times on this website before.

Comment: For example, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2217104 looks at the $p=0.4$ case, though there might be better matches.

Comment: @MishaLavrov thank you very much!